How to list all cached resources?
In Godot 4.3, is there a way to list all cached resources, and their resource_path values? These may be loaded from disk or may belong to packed scenes (which would all be instanced at the time of getting the list).

Are you just asking out of curiosity, or are you having a concrete issue that may benefit from listing which resources are cached or not?

I have since resolved my problem without the need to have a listing of stuff in the resource cache. But I am still interested in whether this is possible or not.
